# Discrete signal testing for periodicity

Tags: discrete-signals, periodic

How would one go about determining if the following discrete time signal `x[n]` is periodic, and if it is, determine its fundamental period?

[image]

I understand that the period for the second exponential term is 6, but apart from that I am unable to further my calculation.

The answer to the question above is:

[image]

but I fail to understand how the equation highlighted in yellow comes to be. Any help with this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first term is just a constant, so it's not relevant to periodicity. The sequence as written is periodic with a fundamental frequency of 1/6.

Your cited solution makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

A discrete signal is periodic only if it's normalized frequency can be expressed as a rational number. In your case:
\begin{equation}
e^{-2}e^{j(n\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4})}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
2 \pi f & = & \frac{\pi}{3} \\
f & = & \frac{1}{6}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Since $1/6$ is rational, it's periodic. Now, you reduce $f$ to its canonical form and apply the definition of $f$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
f & = & \frac{k}{N} \\
\frac{1}{6} & = & \frac{k}{N} \\
N & = & 6 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The signal has a fundamental period of $N=6$.

Solve the same, however, for
\begin{equation}
e^{-2}e^{j(n\frac{1}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4})}
\end{equation}
you'll get
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
2 \pi f & = & \frac{1}{3} \\
f & = & \frac{1}{\pi 6}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
which cannot be expressed as a rational number, hence **not** periodic.

Answer (score 0):

it is more clear if you utilize the Euler's formula
$$
\begin{align}
x[n+N] &= e^{-2}e^{j(\frac{\pi}{3}(n+N)-\frac{\pi}{4})} \\
&= e^{-2}\Big[ \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}n+\frac{\pi}{3}N-\frac{\pi}{4}) -j \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}n+\frac{\pi}{3}N-\frac{\pi}{4})  \Big] 
\end{align}
$$
Using trigonometric identities ( I will leave it as an exercise to you), $x[n]=x[n+N]$ holds if N=6 which is the smallest value that makes the equality to hold. Indeed, the signal is periodic with a fundamental period $N_o=6$.